# Why is the term "chi-square" acceptable?

Tags: chi-squared-test, terminology

It is possible that this is only an English language question (in which case, please move it), but I ask in case there is any statistical or mathematical logic to the answer.

I'm sure the phrase should be "chi-squared" and not "chi-square". It is **χ2** after all.

If we have a square (a box) and its side length is χ, even though its area is χ2, perhaps it *can* be called a χ square. Have I just answered my own question? Sorry.

According to [this blog post](http://languagetips.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/weekly-language-usage-tips-chi-square-or-chi-squared-pick-a-preposition/), "chi-squared" is more correct but "chi-square" is more popular.

Comment: I definitately prefer "chi-squared" but so many people (especially in certain application areas, and also moreso in the US) seem to call it "chi-square" that I sometimes do so myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would agree with the blog post--'chi-squared' is correct.  I suspect 'chi-square' comes from people mis-hearing and/or misunderstanding the term, and the resulting [linguistic drift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_%28linguistics%29).  Although there is a geometric interpretation of statistics (e.g., Fisher preferred to think about statistics from the geometric perspective), the best way to think about this is that when $k$ standard normal random variates have been squared and summed, then the result is a chi-squared random variable on $k$ degrees of freedom.  This is  the standard definition of $\chi^2_k$.  In other words, when you have a chi-squared random variable, there is a sense in which something has already been squared, whereas 'chi-square' sounds like something you are about to do.  (Whether or not you take that literally, it could serve as a useful mnemonic.)

Regarding the $\chi$, Wikipedia has [an interesting story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#History_and_name) about how Pearson came to call it that based on the shorthand he used.

Comment: It can be hard to hear that final "D", so that's one issue. Also, it isn't clear what exactly is being squared. One doesn't talk about "chi" itself (unlike R squared, where it is clear that it is R, squared.

Comment: The fact that it often involves creating a square table certainly can't help either.